# Convert List[Task[Boolean]] to EitherT[Task, Throwable, Unit]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a `List[Task[Boolean]]` and I need to turn it into an `EitherT[Task, Throwable, Unit]`.

I have one possible solution which is

```
EitherT(Task.delay(if (!allAsserts.contains(false)) \/-(()) else -\/(new Exception("BOOM"))))
```

but I was wondering if it's possible to create the `EitherT` without making an explicit call to `Task.delay`.

Perhaps the above code is correct but I was just wondering if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
lazy val toDisjuction: List[Boolean] => \/[Throwable, Unit] = list =>
  if (list.forall(_ == true)) \/-(()) else -\/(new Exception("BOOM"))

val ltb: List[Task[Boolean]] = ???

EitherT(Task.gatherUnordered(ltb) map toDisjunction)
```

I think that's what I was looking for ...